# Google Maps animating multiple symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I simply tried to change google's version of animateCircle() to this so that it would animate multiple icons instead of just one, but it doesn't seem to be working for the icons except the first. Any ideas?

paths is an array of paths that contains other information regarding the path as well.

```
 var icons = [{ icon : lineSymbol, offset : "100%"}, 
                          { icon : lineSymbol, offset : "90%"}]    

function animateArrow() {
        var count = 0;
        offsetId = window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;

            var icons = paths.path.get('icons');
            for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                icons[i].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            }
            paths.path.set('icons', icons);
        }, 20);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Note: `path` is not shown here.
`percentSpaced` should be changed according to the spacing you desire, i.e. 20 for 20% spacing between the symbols.

```
function animateArrow(path) {
                var count = 0, icons = new Array();
                var percentSpaced = 20;
                var intervalTime = 20; // miliseconds


                var lineSymbol = {
                    path : google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                    strokeColor : "#000000",
                    strokeOpacity : .95,
                    strokeWeight : 10,
                    fillColor : "#FFFFFF",
                    fillOpacity : .7
                };

                for (var i = 0; i < 100/percentSpaced; i++) {
                    icons.push({ icon : lineSymbol });
                }

                path.set("icons", icons);

                offsetId = window.setInterval(function() {
                    count = (count + 1) % 200;

                    var icons = paths.path.get('icons');
                    for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                        icons[i].offset = ((count / 2) + (i * percentSpaced)) % 100 + '%';
                    }
                    path.set("icons", icons);
                }, intervalTime);
            }
```

There are two things you have to consider:

1) Count is set up assuming there is only 1 icon. (Hence the `(i * percentSpaced)`)

2) Icons should start at the beginning again if their percentage exceeds 100%. (Hence the `% 100` at the end)